# When closing an active Terminator window, it directly exists without showing any warning pop up

Tags: command-line, terminator

If my terminator is actively running a process like Vim, and I accidentally close the window, the Terminator directly exists without showing any warning pop up.How to enable the pop up?

Comment: Just found that the process I ran in Terminator was still running in the background